# Windows phone app that extends horizontally

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to create a timeline app that shows items horizontally on a windows phone page.
Do you know which controls should i use? Are there limitations in size (width, in this case) ?

Comment: Can you porvide an example (e.g. a mock up image) of what you're trying to achieve please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completed a similar effect with a horizontal scrolling graph. You can view a video of the effect at [my website](http://compiledexperience.com/windows-phone-7/left-to-spend). to see if  it's what wanting.

It's achieved by having a ScrollViewer with the VerticalScrollBarVisibility set to Disabled and the HoriztonalScrollBaryVisibiltiy set to Auto.

The content of the ScrollViewer in my case was the chart with a hard coded width of 1000.

There is a hard limit of 2048px I believe for any single element.

Answer (score 1):

There is a size limitation on any Silverlight UI control that it cannot be more than 2048px either horizontally or vertically.
Depending on your precise requirements it may be possible to combine multiple items to create the desired effect. However, you should carefully consider and test how users will be able to work with something much wider than the screen.